# Product Variants Data updated with last record Every time in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5.3, insert-update

I'm trying to update my products with dynamic variants. There is no issue in adding or deleting but when I trying to update, every time it updates with the last record on every field.

I'm trying to update dynamic variants where I have inserted...

- **color - red**
- **shape -square**

It's about dynamic form-fields, inserts work properly but when I am trying to update it, it updates the first value with both the filled and the second value with both the field and I won't be able to distinguish the field because of the Blade file returns in form of an array.

When I am trying to update with any value it repeats the last value in both the fields, so the output looks like...

- **shape-square**
- **shape-square**

**Controller**

```
<?php

public function updateProducts($id, Request $request)
{
    $featured = Input::has('featured') ? true : false;

    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $product->update(array(
        'product_name' => $request->input('product_name'),
        'product_qty' => $request->input('product_qty'),
        'product_sku' => $request->input('product_sku'),
        'price' => $request->input('price'),
        'reduced_price' => $request->input('reduced_price'),
        'cat_id' => $request->input('cat_id'),
        'brand_id' => $request->input('brand_id'),
        'featured' => $featured,
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
        'product_spec' => $request->input('product_spec'),
    ));

    $product->update($request->all());

    $variants = VariantsOption::where('products_id', $id)->get();
    $test = $request->all();

    foreach ($variants as $v) {
        $x = $v->id;
        foreach ($test['variants_id'] as $key => $attrib) {
            $var_name = $test['txt'][$key];
            $varid = $attrib;
            $variants = new VariantsOption;
            $data = array(
                'variants_id' => $varid,
                'variants_name' => $var_name
            );
            $variants->where('id', '=', $x)->update($data);
        }
    }

    return redirect('/admin/products/');
}
```

[image: database image click here]

Comment: Need to include where condition while updating the database

Comment: No buddy.. where condition must while updating any information..u can just print your query before fire it.. generally it is happen when u dont get id means $id. that's why it may be happen..so request you to print the query first.

Comment: get output for $variants and check whats output?

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: i have updated my question...check it

Comment: already included where condition sona                                            $variants = VariantsOption::where('products_id', $id)->get();

Comment: can u print the query before the execution  ? @juleedadhaniya

Answer (score 0):

use following in your class

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
```

OR add exception handler within your function

```
// Will return a ModelNotFoundException if no user with that id
try
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
}
// catch(Exception $e) catch any exception
catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    dd(get_class_methods($e)) // lists all available methods for exception object
    dd($e)
}
```

It looks like product with that `$id` is not found so on update it is adding new product in database.